# Separately reading a word like "a-b-" from a text file and deleting

Tags: c++, file, text

The first question is I have code like this for reading from the text file:

```cpp
File >> product.projectNo >> product.date
     >> product.productNo >> product.productQ
     >> product.productTotalPrice;
```

And I write `productNo`, `productQ` and `productTotalPrice` to the file, separated by `-` because there can be more than one. Here is an example of the text file:

```
17 5 17-7051-10- 9-8-11- 720-616-55-
```

The last one `720-616-55-` (`productTotalPrice`) is a list of prices. I need to read them separately and add them. So: `720+616+55`. How can I do that?

The second question is I need to delete any of them, meaning `productNo` `17-7051-10-`, needs to delete `17-`. How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you just read a line at a time and then parse each line according to your rules? Read up on tokenizing, lexing and parsing.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your problem is reading each word from your file. This can be done using:

```cpp
std::string word0, word1;
std::getline(file, word0, ' ');
std::getline(file, word1, ' ');
...
```

Of course, the above code assumes that there is exactly one `' '` is being used as a separator between words.

The next problem is parsing your prices. This can be done using `std::stoi`:

```cpp
size_t index;
int price0 = `std::stoi(word, &index);
word = word.substr(index + 1);
int price1 = `std::stoi(word, &index);
word = word.substr(index + 1);
int price2 = `std::stoi(word);

int totalPrice = price0 + price1 + price2;
```

This works because [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) returns the index of the first character which is not part of the integer. So this would be the `-` separator between your numbers.

As for the second part of your question: You wouldn't delete `17-` as a string. Instead you should simply ignore the `17` before adding it onto the sum or you should remove it from the list of numbers after parsing.

Comment: I have worked so hard on it and searched more with inspired by your writings. Solved, thank you so much.